# Output groups one per line, with group name and group ID

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Here is the information about the groups to which I belong, from the `id` command. <s>I've made it so the output would be easier to read.</s> I'm including this output "exactly" as it came back from the command line. (Thanks @EdMorton.)

```
$id
uid=1(me) gid=545(Users) groups=545(Users),66049(CONSOLE LOGON),11(Authenticated Users),4095(CurrentSession),66048(LOCAL)
```

Here is the output I want, comma delimited, with one group name and its GID per line:

```
$ some-great-command
'Users',545
'CONSOLE LOGON',66049
'Authenticated Users',11
'CurrentSession',4095
'LOCAL',66048
```

I came up with a horrendous way to do this:

```
$ id | sed 's/\(.*groups=\)\(.*$\)/\2/' | awk -F "," '{ for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print $i;}' | sed 's/\(^[[:digit:]]\+\)[(]\([A-Za-z +_]\+\)[)]$/'"'"'\2'"'"',\1/'
```

(I'll put it here again with a little nicer on-screen format, using `\`)

```
$ id | sed 's/\(.*groups=\)\(.*$\)/\2/' | \
awk -F "," '{ for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print $i;}' | \
sed 's/\(^[[:digit:]]\+\)[(]\([A-Za-z +_]\+\)[)]$/'"'"'\2'"'"',\1/'
```

but I can't help but think there must be a better (or at least shorter and more elegant) way to accomplish this process. Can anyone share such a solution?

**Note**: One reason I'm doing this is that, sometimes, `getent group GID` is a bit finicky where I work. I've looked at some other posts, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163910/how-to-get-groupname-when-i-have-the-groupid), but it didn't have the answer I wanted.

A nicer-to-read version of the `id` output which IS NOT THE SAME AS WHAT THE CONSOLE GAVE! There are newline characters after `(Users)` (note the space after the right paren) and after `(LOCAL),` (no space after the comma).

```
$ id
uid=1(me) gid=545(Users) 
groups=545(Users),66049(CONSOLE LOGON),
11(Authenticated Users),4095(CurrentSession),66048(LOCAL)
```

Real `id` output:

```
$ id
uid=1(me) gid=545(Users) groups=545(Users),66049(CONSOLE LOGON),11(Authenticated Users),4095(CurrentSession),66048(LOCAL)
```

Comment: Very nice and detailed post!!! It's a pleasure to answer! If only all posts could be like this...

Comment: @EdMorton. I'm going to remove the part that's "easier to read" with what was, as you suspected, an extra newline. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I appreciate your comment, @Allan!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And there comes `perl`:

```
$ id | perl -pe "s/.*=/,/;s/,(\d+)\(([^)]+)\)/'\2',\1\n/g"                                                                 
'arobert',1000
'adm',4
'cdrom',24
'sudo',27
'dip',30
'plugdev',46
'lpadmin',113
'sambashare',128
```

**Explanations:**

Two find and replace commands will be executed:

- `s/.*groups=/,/` is used to remove everything before the groups definition
- `s/,(\d+)\(([^)]+)\)/'\2',\1\n/g` will put in place the following actions detailed @[demo](https://regex101.com/r/tdRsoj/1/)

It would be difficult to write something shorter than this. 
Also if you are already good with `sed` and `regex`, than `perl` can be a nice plus to add to your list of skills.

As mentioned by [**Ed Morton**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton), the current `perl` command generates an extra `EOL` at the end of the output. If you want to remove it you can use the following enhanced `perl` command:

```
$ id | perl -pe "s/.*=/,/;s/,(\d+)\(([^)]+)\)/'\2',\1\n/g;s/\n\n/\n/"
```

Thanks [**Ed**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)!!!

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks! I have adapted the `perl` command accordingly.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I didn't care if the answer were with `awk` and `sed`. For elegance (or maybe just brevity) and a great explanation, this one gets accepted. I'll definitely brush off my `perl` skills so that it's part of my "list of skills". Thanks!

Comment: P.S. I verified this one. I guess I'll have to add _something like_ the following line to my `.bashrc`: `alias some-great-command="id | perl -pe "s/.*=/,/;s/,(\d+)\(([^)]+)\)/'\2',\1\n/g;s/\n\n/\n/""`. I just need to figure out the [escapes](https://xkcd.com/1638/)! : )

Comment: Code golfing challenge accepted: Slightly shorter: `id | perl -pe "s/.*=//;s/,/\n/g;s/(\d+)\((.+?)\)/'\2',\1/g"`.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk -v RS=, -F'[()=]' '{print "\047"$(NF-1)"\047,"$(NF-2)}'
```

e.g. given this input data:

```
$ cat file
uid=1(me) gid=545(Users) groups=545(Users),66049(CONSOLE LOGON),11(Authenticated Users),4095(CurrentSession),66048(LOCAL)
```

and using `cat file` in place of `id`:

```
$ cat file | awk -v RS=, -F'[()=]' '{print "\047"$(NF-1)"\047,"$(NF-2)}'
'Users',545
'CONSOLE LOGON',66049
'Authenticated Users',11
'CurrentSession',4095
'LOCAL',66048
```

Comment: I really like this one. I +1-ed it, since it uses `awk` as I did. I piped my `id` output to the command, and it worked like a charm. Thanks! P.S., this would win a [CodeGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) challenge for least bytes ... let me check ...

Comment: It was a hard battle between this and @Allan 's.

Comment: `$ echo 'awk -v RS=, -F'"'"'[()=]'"'"' '"'"'{print "\047"$(NF-1)"\047,"$(NF-2)}'"'"'' | wc -m` gives `60`. This would be the CodeGolf winner (at least if we use @Allan 's command that gets rid of the extra EOL).

Answer (score 3):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -v s1="'" -F"[)(=,]"  '/uid/{print s1 $(NF-1) s1 OFS $(NF-2);next} /groups/{print s1 $6 s1 OFS s1 $5 s1 ORS s1 $(NF-2) s1 OFS $(NF-3);next} /CurrentSession/{print s1 $2 s1 OFS $1 ORS s1 $(NF-1) s1  OFS $(NF-2)}' OFS=,  Input_file
```

OR

```
id | awk -v s1="'" -F"[)(=,]"  '/uid/{print s1 $(NF-1) s1 OFS $(NF-2);next} /groups/{print s1 $6 s1 OFS s1 $5 s1 ORS s1 $(NF-2) s1 OFS $(NF-3);next} /CurrentSession/{print s1 $2 s1 OFS $1 ORS s1 $(NF-1) s1  OFS $(NF-2)}' OFS=,
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -v s1="'" -F"[)(=,]"  '
/uid/                    {  print s1 $(NF-1) s1 OFS $(NF-2);                          next}
/groups/                 {  print s1 $6 s1 OFS s1 $5 s1 ORS s1 $(NF-2) s1 OFS $(NF-3);next}
/CurrentSession/         {  print s1 $2 s1 OFS $1 ORS s1 $(NF-1) s1  OFS $(NF-2);         }
' OFS=,   Input_file
```

OR

```
id | awk -v s1="'" -F"[)(=,]"  '
/uid/                    {  print s1 $(NF-1) s1 OFS $(NF-2);                          next}
/groups/                 {  print s1 $6 s1 OFS s1 $5 s1 ORS s1 $(NF-2) s1 OFS $(NF-3);next}
/CurrentSession/         {  print s1 $2 s1 OFS $1 ORS s1 $(NF-1) s1  OFS $(NF-2);         }
' OFS=,
```

Comment: @Allan Did you say [_a bit long_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50382787/4162356) ?

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure what I should use as `Input File`. for the first versions (`awk` before `id`.) Is this simply  `$ id > Input_file ` or is it a system file somewhere?

Comment: @bballdave025, I have added `id | awk command...` too check it out if that helps you?

Comment: They do help me. It especially helped me to understand what was going on.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ id |
  awk 'BEGIN{ RS=OFS=",";q="\047" }
  {
      n=split($0,a,"=")
      split(a[n],a,"[()]")
      print q a[2] q,a[1]
  }'
'Users',545
'CONSOLE LOGON',66049
'Authenticated Users',11
'CurrentSession',4095
'LOCAL',66048
```

Works nicely with gawk and mawk but bwk <s>outputed an extra</s> broke the last line:

```
'',
```

Comment: Wow this `awk` answer is amazing~~~ +1!!! Wondering if it is shorter than my `perl` solution lol

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed and awk :

```
$ id | sed 's/,/\n/g' | awk -F '[()=]' '{print $(NF-1)","$(NF-2)}'
```

Comment: I have to +1 this one, since you used the same tools I did, but elegan-ized it.

Comment: It doesn't put the single quote around the group name, which was going to be needed for my application of the command. I'm sure that's readily fixed. I tried figuring out how to put the [escape sequence](https://xkcd.com/1638/) in the `awk` command, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @bballdave025, Yep, it only shows how close your were. !